# Angular-animate not working with ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I am using **Angular animate** to show a **`div`** when a **`button`** is clicked.

This is the **`button`** which shows the **`div`**:

```
<input type='button'  value='+'   ng-click=addRoom(x) ng-model="collapse">
```

This is the **`div`** which is shown when the **`button`** is pressed.

```
<div class="row coll" ng-show="collapse">

   <div ng-repeat="data in room[x.room_type_id]">

            Adult:<select ng-model="selAdultValue" ng-change="setAdultPrice(x)" >
                    <option ng-repeat="a in x.planNames">{{a}}</option>
                </select>

   </div>

   <button class="btn pull-right" ng-class="{'btn-primary': book_status == 'AVAILABLE', 'btn-info disabled': book_status == 'NOT AVAILABLE'}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#book_now" ng-click="afterTax()">Book Now</button>

</div>
```

This is working fine but the **`div`** is shown instantly instead of having a smooth transition.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation_css)

I have included the `angular` and `angular-animate` script in my **HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and **Injected** it in my `Module`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Here's the **addRoom** `function`

```
$scope.addRoom = function(x){
     $scope.collapse = true;
}
```

Here's the **CSS**:

```
.coll{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add height to CSS:
.coll{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
}

Comment: @TekriwalD Not working. The div is being shown when I click the button but instead of a smooth and slow transition it is being displayed instantly like a normal ng-show and ng-hide

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height to the div by CSS. So, update your CSS to :

```
.coll{ 
 transition: all linear 0.5s;
 height: 100px;
 }
```

Hope this works for you . 
Thank you .

Comment: Not working. The div is being shown when I click the button but instead of a smooth and slow transition it is being displayed instantly like a normal ng-show and ng-hide